# Tags cannot properly represent underscores

Tags: discussion, tags, special-characters

I just [created a question with an HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684091/any-python-modules-out-there-that-do-anything-with-http-accept-langauge).  This value is built into Python, so I believe I need an underscore to do justice in describing my question.  Is there any hope in getting an underscore in a created tag?

Comment: is there a problem with using dashes instead of underscores? At any rate, HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE is not a good tag.

Comment: Upper case letters are also disallowed. Strike two.

Comment: @yhw42 and can you tell me why upper case letters are disallowed?  I am not getting any whys ...  I think it is more because that is the way it has always been done,

Comment: @demongolem: If uppercase letters were allowed and tags were made case-sensitive, are we really going to have to create tag synonyms for [.net] [.Net] [.NEt] [.NET] [.nEt] [.nET] and [.neT]?

Comment: @BoltClock - you missed out [.NeT]

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I knew it :/

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because no one ever intended to have a separate tag for every language constant (in addition to limiting the number of possible permutations so people are more likely to use the same tag, as mentioned by BoltClock).

Using tags related to the *application* of the constant will do fine, such as [constants](/questions/tagged/constants) and [internationalization](/questions/tagged/internationalization).

By the time you get down to [compiler-constants](/questions/tagged/compiler-constants), there's only **two** questions. If we start- creating individual tags for constants we'd be lucky if they were *ever* used again.